# jQuery - Get the value of the closest text box

Tags: jquery

How to get the value of the closest text-box, while clicking the button? Actually, I'm creating a table with five columns, where two columns will have dynamically generated text-boxes and each of it will have separate id. The last column will contain save button. When the button is clicked, those values should be saved in the db. I've tried like this:

```
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var table;
    //var c = 0;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });     

        table = jQuery("#table_billing").dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": "includes/inc-billing2-db.php?mode=billing_dataTable",
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "aTargets": [2],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type="text" class="form-control invoice_number" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number_'+ a +'" placeholder="Invoice Number" required="required" onblur="getvalue(this)">';
                            var x = row[3];
                            var y = row[4];

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "aTargets": [3],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type="text" class="form-control date" name="invoice_date" id="invoice_date_'+ b +'" placeholder="Invoice Date" required="required">';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "aTargets": [4],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type="button" class="btn-group btn-default btn-sm save" value="Save" name="save_bill" id="save_bill" onclick="jQuery(this).save(' + row[3] + ', ' + row[4] + ', ' + jQuery("#invoice_number_0").val() + ');">';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
                    a = a + 1;
                    b = b + 1;
                    //c = c + 1;
                }
            });

            jQuery.fn.save = function (id, contract_invoice_request_id, value){
                alert(id);
                alert(contract_invoice_request_id);
                alert(value);

            if(jQuery("#invoice_number").val() == ''){
                alert("Please enter the invoice number!");
                jQuery("#invoice_number").focus();
            }
            if(jQuery("#invoice_date").val() == ''){
                alert("Please select the invoice date!");
                jQuery("#invoice_date").focus();
            }

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/inc-billing-db.php?mode=save_billing",
                data:{ "contract_id": aData[2],
                    "invoice_number": jQuery("#save_bill").val(),
                    "invoice_date": jQuery("#invoice_date").val()
                    },
                success: function(data, text){
                        jQuery.msgbox_success(data.message);
                        jQuery("#billing_"+this.id).closest('tr').remove();
                        jQuery("#date_"+this.id).closest('tr').remove();

                }       
            });
    }
}); 
function getvalue(txt){
                alert(txt.id);
                var tr = $("#"+ txt.id).closest('tr');
                console.log(tr);
                var data = table.row(tr).data();
                alert(data);
                data.invoice_number = txt.val();
            }
```

But, I get the error as table.row is not a function. What is wrong and what should I do?

Comment: in getvalue function replace `var data = table.row(tr).data();` with `tr.data();`

Comment: @Psyco Killers: You mean like this: var data = tr.data();?

Comment: yes because you have defined it previously.

Comment: I tried it, but the alert I get is [object, object], I don't get the value I type in the text box and the next error is txt.val() is not a function. What's wrong there?

Comment: replace `var data = table.row(tr).data();` with `var data = table.row(tr).text();` assuming that you need the text. & `                data.invoice_number = txt.val();` with `data.invoice_number = txt;`

Comment: I get the same response: table.row is not a function. :( Actually what's wrong here? Since I'm new to this, it's difficult to understand.

Comment: sorry you need to replace `var data = table.row(tr).data();` with `var data = tr.text();` . :) no its easy but needs practice.

Comment: This is working, but the values what I get are from the previous columns rather from this text box. This is not the desired one, I should get the value from the "txt.id" text box.

Comment: what you get in `alert(txt.id);` ?

Comment: I would recommend getting data from the datatables model, rather than the DOM. Change your `jQuery("#table_billing").dataTable` to `jQuery("#table_billing").DataTable`, notice the uppercase D. Lower case 'd' will return a jQuery object, uppercase 'D' will return the datatables api. You should then be able to call `table.row`

Comment: than you replace `var tr = $("#"+ txt.id).closest('tr');` with `var tr = $("#"+ txt.id);`

Comment: While using tr.text() I get the values in the previous columns but they are clubbed together. Is there any way to get them separately? @PsycoKillers

Comment: Thanks @EricGuan. I'll try.

Comment: try `tr.first().text();`

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Comment: if there are too many tr you can use [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: @PsycoKillers There are five columns in a row. First two columns are filled by the values that are coming from the db. Next two columns should be filled ie text-boxes created dynamically with unique id. The fifth column contains a button.

Comment: @PsycoKillers even after using tr.first().text() I get all the values clubbed together. Is there any other option?

Comment: @RRR I have shared what I've done in the question itself. In HTML I've just described the dataTable and its column names.

Comment: have you replaced `var tr = $("#"+ txt.id).closest('tr');` with `var tr = $("#"+ txt.id);` ?

Comment: Yes, I did and get null ie I don't get any value

Comment: sorry but I fail to understand what you are trying to achieve as you have mentioned static IDs in your query for validation and in `getvalue(txt)` function you are trying to get tr data which will return object as it contains textbox in it ...

Comment: @PsycoKillers How can I pass the value of that text box as a parameter to the "save" function?

Comment: you should try something like this... https://jsfiddle.net/143Lrq7j/1/

Comment: @SaiKrishna you can call the function with that argument like `save(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code

```
function getvalue(txt){
    var txtValue = $(txt).val();

 console.log(txtValue);
 alert(txtValue);

 var tr = $(txt).closest('tr');
 console.log(tr);

 // note set correct column number
 tr.find("td").eq(0).text(txtValue);

}
```

Comment: Same problem is arising Riyas, it shows table .row is not a function. I tried using tr.text() which gave me all the values in the previous columns together. Is there any way to get them separately?

Comment: you get text box value?

Comment: I got the value from the text box but I could not get the value in the previous columns.